# Python - Unexpected output in list comprehension using modulus

Tags: python, list-comprehension, modulus

Why does `filtered_lst_2` have different values than `filtered_lst_1` though they have the same logic? I must be missing something obvious. Thanks!

```
lst = [x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11)]
print(lst) # [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]

filtered_lst_1 = []
  for x in lst:
    if x % 4 == 0:
      filtered_lst_1.append(x)
print(filtered_lst_1) # [8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]

filtered_lst_2 = ([x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11) if x % 4 == 0])
print(filtered_lst_2) # [64, 512]
```

Comment: The confusion might come from using the name `x` in both cases. Use `for y in lst:` for the explicit loop and consider `y`’s relationship to `x` in the first list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the order in which you're doing operations. In the first, you're cubing first, then taking the modulo. In the second, you're taking the modulo **before** cubing.

To make the second output equal to the first:

```
filtered_lst_2 = ([x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11) if x ** 3 % 4 == 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You coul try `filtered_lst_2 = ([x ** 3 for x in range(1, 11) if (x ** 3) % 4 == 0])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first answer makes sense.